# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send') node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am writing a discord bot with discord.js and mineflyer however I keep getting this error. I have gone through many threads but I can't find the answer even though I know it will be something obvious. The snippets of the code;

```
import mineflayer from "mineflayer";
import { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials, EmbedBuilder } from 'discord.js';

const discordBot = new Client({
  intents: [ GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages, GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
  ], 'partials': [Partials.Channel, Partials.Message, Partials.User, Partials.GuildMember, Partials.Reaction]
});

const options = {
  host: server,
  username: ign,
  auth: 'microsoft'
};

const bot = mineflayer.createBot(options);

discordBot.login(process.env.token1)

discordBot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`The Discord bot ${discordBot.user.username} is ready!`);
  discordBot.channels.cache.get('987349559724372059').send(`The Discord bot ${discordBot.user.username} is ready!`);
});

bot.on('login', () => {
  console.log('Minecraft bot has logged in!');
});

bot.on('message', async (jsonMsg, position) => {
  if (jsonMsg != "") return;
  if (position === 'system') {
    await discordBot.channels.cache.get('987349559724372059').send(`${jsonMsg}`);
  } else if (position === 'game_info') {
    await discordBot.channels.cache.get('987349559724372059').send(`${jsonMsg}`);
  }
});
```

When I run the script I get:

```
Minecraft bot has logged in!
file:///home/runner/InGameChat/index.js:138
        await discordBot.channels.cache.get('987349559724372059').send(`${jsonMsg}`);
                                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
```

I think it is to do with the discordBot not logging in but I don't know why but it could be something else.

Comment: Where do you have this `await discordBot.channels.cache.get('987349559724372059').send(`${jsonMsg}`)`? It's not included in the code snippet you posted.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I copy and pasted in between trying different things so the versions where slightly mismatched but fixed that inconsistency. It should be line 31

Comment: does your discordbot login?  you didn't show that output